# Nodeunit will not run nodeunit command just give error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodeunit

Hi I try to get Nodeunit install but when i try and run the nodeunit command it just give the a error. The screenshot below is the error . Any help would be appreciated thanks.

running window 10 and installed with the command 'npm install nodeunit -g'

[image]

Comment: Do u have test folder in ur project?

Comment: nope just following along with this tutorial as i am new to node https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=learning-programming-javascript&author=scott-allen&name=learning-programming-javascript-m7&clip=1&mode=live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error on your screenshot shows that you do not have a folder from which nodeunit get tests by default, you must create folder named 'test' in current directory, and and put it in test files

Comment: thanks is there any way to changing the default folder which nodeunit will use to tests the files? thanks again.

Comment: you must specify folder as cli argument for nodeunit command. example: `nodeunit my_folder`. You can also specify js files with tests: `nodeunit my_test.js`